# VueJS v-for on Django template

Tags: django, typescript, vue.js

I'm using vuejs with typescript on Django template and I'm facing `Property or method "ingredient" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property`

my vue code is like this.

```
export class MyApp extends Vue {
    constructor(selector) {
        super();
        this.$options.delimiters = ['${', '}'];
        this.$options.el = '#app';
        this.$options.data = {
            'ingredients': [{"id": 1, "name": "test"}]
        }
    }
}
```

my template is like this.

```
<tr @for="obj in ingredients">
  ${obj}  <-- error
</tr>
```

When I just set property and it works with this delimiters. But, when I use v-for and can't get the obj..

Comment: Have you tried this answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56466887/how-to-write-a-v-for-on-django

Comment: @YashMaheshwari In my cane, v-for="n in 3" doesn't work and faces same problem..